# query subsubtag in Document

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML Document like this:

```
...
<sometag>
    <subtag>
        <subsubtag someattr="foo" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bla" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bar" />
    </subtag>
</sometag>
...
```

i have it in an `org.w3c.dom.Document` and now need to get all `subsubtag` inside a `subtag` inside a `sometag`. Currently i query for all nodes that are a `sometag`, get all childs that are `subtag`, get all childs from here and so on...
i cant query directly for all subsubtag because they can be listed on other places in the document too.

is there any faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath for such complex query in XML files. It will be worth the effort of learning curve. Basically, in Xpath , you would just need to write

```
/sometag/subtag/subsubtag
```

Comment: ahh thanks, now i know how this is called: gives me instant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java